# facing "AuthenticationError" in sending push notification in FCM in POSTMAN

Tags: firebase, vuejs2, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

The error that I am facing:-

[image]
I am sending a POST request to `FCM` with following details:-

[image]

where `key` is my `server key`

[image]

where `to` is the key that I have generated using the flowing code in vue 2:-

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.register("firebase-messaging-sw.js", {scope: "firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope"})
  .then((registration) => {
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging.getToken({
      serviceWorkerRegistration: registration,
      vapidKey: "MY WEB PUSH CERTIFICATE KEY",
    }).then((token) =>console.log("///////firebase service worker token", token));

  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

In the above snippet, `vapid key` is from `Web Push Certificate Key Pair` :-

[image]

Comment: Which browser are you using to test this? I am getting the same error when trying using Firefox. But testing on Chrome works as expected.